# what is the typehint of plotly objects in python3

Tags: plotly, python-typing

What should be the type hint of the following example:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

def update_scene_callback():
   ....

def scatter_plot(input_data, layout):
    fig = go.FigureWidget(input_data)
    fig.update_layout(object_layout)
    scatter = fig.data[0]
    
    scatter.on_click(update_scene_callback)
    return fig
```

type(fig) is `plotly.graph_objs._figurewidget.FigureWidget`
what should be the type of input and output of `scatter_plot` function?

Also, assume that I have a dataframe as input variable of a function. But I don't want the dataframe to be changed inside the function. Is there any way to assign a type to an input variable, so that we can be sure the variable is not going to be changed inside the function?

Comment: Do you mind to add a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Are you looking for a dropdown with input box? [dropdown](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/)